# How to show the Popup that inputs details one time per session

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, local-storage

When a user enters my website, I want to show a popup in 3 seconds. I expect the user to input his details. once he has entered and submitted, I don't want that popup to appear again for that particular session.
I have used php to input the data in the database and the POST name is "save"

Here is my code for pop-up dialog box and the script.js to show it.

Thankyou.

```
<div class="login-popup">
     <div class="box">
      
     <div class="form">
          <div class="close">X</div>
     <h1 style="font-size:14px">Please Enter your Details Correctly</h1>
             
     <form action="index.php" method="POST">
           <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
        </div>
               <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" name="email" required>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <input type="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" name="phone" required>
        </div>
                
            <button name="save" class="btn">Enter<button>
           </div> 
     </form>
             
             
     </div>
  </div>
```

```
const loginPopup = document.querySelector(".login-popup");
const close = document.querySelector(".close");

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
setTimeout(function(){
loginPopup.classList.add("show");
},7000)

})

close.addEventListener("click",function(){
loginPopup.classList.remove("show");
})
```

Comment: you can add a field in session storage and it will last per the life of that tab/session.

   `window.addEventListener("load", () =>  setTimeout(() => {
      if (!sessionStorage.getItem("hasFormSubmitted")) { 
        loginPopup.classList.add("show");
      }
    }, 7000));
  
    close.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (!sessionStorage.getItem("hasFormSubmitted")) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("hasFormSubmitted", "true");
      }
    });`

Comment: I tried with the code above. Didnt get.